# Apache archiva returns http error 503

Tags: apache, http-status-code-503, archiva

I am using apache Archiva v. 2.2.0 under Windows Server 2012 R2, Java version 1.8.0_60 inside VirtualBox. It used to work for quite a long time before Windows autoupdate.

After Windows autoupdate I am getting an error message when going to archiva url: HTTP ERROR: 503 . Problem accessing /. Reason: Service Unavailable, Powered by Jetty://.

The Apache Archiva service is running. No error logs are generated. Restarting or even reinstalling of the service has no impact.

After rolling back of Windows update I restore the normal operation of Archiva, but mysteriously, just once, i.e. stopping and restarting of Archiva will cause the same HTTP ERROR 503.

The log file do not indicate any problem or error cuase.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04 the same issue is caused by usage of Java/OpenJDK 9, see https://superuser.com/questions/1206855/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-when-u for details.

Comment: For 2.2.4, had to roll back to Java 8 to get it to work.  Java 11 for sure did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I've found out that the jetty configuration file jetty.xml in ARCHIVA_BASE\conf got corrupted.

Solution:

1. Stop archiva service
2. Replace jetty.xml with either a fresh one or from last known working
   backup. A fresh copy of jetty.xml can be downloaded from [archiva web
   site](https://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi) as an apache-archiva-2.2.0-bin.zip. File location within the
   zip file is apache-archiva-2.2.1\conf\jetty.xml
3. Start archiva service

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. 
I restarted archiva using `./path/to/archiva/apache-archiva-2.2.0/bin/archiva console`

for you, since you are using windows `.\bin\archiva.bat console`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was complaining about ClassDefNotFound errors, this was because I didn't set my JAVA_HOME properly (on Mac OS). After fixing this, the program worked. Maybe that was your issue.